# Sharing an API gateway between micro services in Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm fairly new to Serverless. I recently hit the dreaded 200 resource limit issue on Serverless and hence I'm trying to break down my services and use a common API gateway between them but I keep getting `Another resource with the same parent already has this name: assets`. I am using the common api gateway property because I don't have a domain for this service.

This is my main `serverless.yml`

```
    app: xxx
    org: xxx
    service: xxx
    provider:
      name: aws
      runtime: nodejs12.x
      region: xxx
functions: 
....
    resources:
      Outputs:

        ApiGatewayRestId:
          Value:
            Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
          Export:
            Name: assetsapi-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-ApiGatewayRestId
        RootResourceId:
          Value:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - ApiGatewayRestApi
              - RootResourceId
          Export:
            Name: assetsapi-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-RootResourceId
        IamRoleLambdaExecution:
          Value:
            Fn::GetAtt: IamRoleLambdaExecution.Arn
          Export:
            Name: assetsapi-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-IamRoleLambdaExecution
        ApiGatewayResourceMaintainence:
          Value:
            Ref: ApiGatewayResourceMaintainence
          Export:
            Name: assetsapi-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-ApiGatewayResourceMaintainence
    Resources:
        # Rest API
        ApiGatewayRestApi:
          Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
          Properties:
            Name: assetsapi
            Description: assets API Gateway

        # Rest API Paths
        ApiGatewayResourceMaintainence:
          Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
          Properties:
            RestApiId: { Ref: 'ApiGatewayRestApi' }
            ParentId: { Fn::GetAtt: 'ApiGatewayRestApi.RootResourceId' }
            PathPart: maintain
```

This the serverless.yml file for the second service which resides inside the path `api/maintainence/serverless.yml`

```
    service: maintainencemanagementservice
    custom:
      stage: '${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}'
      region: ${opt:region, self:provider.region}
      prefix: ${self:service}-${self:custom.region}-${self:custom.stage}
      rootApiGatewayId: 'assets-api-${self:custom.region}-${self:custom.stage}-restApiId'
      rootApiGatewayResourceId: 'assets-api-${self:custom.region}-${self:custom.stage}-rootResourceId'
    provider:
      name: aws
      runtime: nodejs12.x
      stage: dev
      region: xxxx
      apiGateway:
        restApiId:
          Fn::ImportValue: assetsapi-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-ApiGatewayRestId
        restApiRootResourceId:
          Fn::ImportValue: assetsapi-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-RootResourceId
        restApiResources:
          /maintainence:
            Fn::ImportValue: assetsapi-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-ApiGatewayResourceMaintainence,
      role:
        Fn::ImportValue: assetsapi-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-IamRoleLambdaExecution
```

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally used the same path beginning in the second service function `i.e. assets/addmaintainence` Changing it to `maintainence/addmaintainence` did the trick